# Xcode Playground Framework import

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, swift, swift-playground

While I was working with the Xcode Playground I realized sometimes I have to import Foundation although I already imported Cocoa.
Without it functions like *sin*, *cos* or *lowercaseString* refuse to work.
As I noticed this morning *NSCharacterSet* is also not available.

Why it this so?
Doesn't the Cocoa Framework already include the Foundation Framework?

At least this is what I learned during Objective-C development.

My Xcode is Version 6.1 (6A1052d)

```
import Cocoa
import Foundation // Does not work without this line

var resultSin = sin(M_PI)
```

Comment: What version of Xcode are we talking about here?

Comment: did you get wroking?

Answer (score 1):

It works just fine, see picture below.[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works with UIKit but not with Cocoa like it wrote. Try it!

Comment: Not with me! Now I am confused!